# Custom View: should I set "android:Widget" as parent for my view's style?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-styles

I've created a custom view that wraps xml-layout with some text fields. While I was defining the default style for this view and digging into the internal styles of the android, I noticed that there is such an element as `android:Widget`. And I have a question - should I use it as a parent for my custom widgets?

Just in case, here is the XML layout of my view and its default style:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:orientation="vertical"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dashed_circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:text="12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/default_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            tools:text="6" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        tools:text="Защита" />
</merge>
```

```xml
<style name="Widget.ParamView" parent=""> <!-- parent="android:Widget" ??? -->
    <item name="valueTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
    <item name="defaultValueTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
    <item name="labelTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no need to explicitly declare that parent relationship: a style named `foo.bar` automatically inherits from `foo`, so `Widget.ParamView` automatically inherits from `Widget` if you don't do anything else.

As far as whether this is a good thing: all it does in the actual implementation is [set the `textAppearance` attr to the current style's `textAppearance`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/ea224951e010bdfe672b51fabe8db335e44dc9cf:frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml;l=317) (I'm not quite sure what the point of this is, to be honest).

Basically, it doesn't hurt much, doesn't help much.  There's not a lot there.  It's mostly up to you.